# How to use an approximate string matching algorithm in android sqlite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i want to create an android application that can search word in sqlite database using approximate string matching.
for example if someone misspelled the word "switch" with " swithc", the sistem will correct the word and show message "did you mean 'switch' ".

its like google that can correct wrong word. how can i do it ?

Comment: it might not be your case, but take a look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html

Comment: I think "Full Text Search" is what you need, check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/1976320/15141

Answer (score -1):

have a look at this answer

[Java: how to find the most probable string in a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650409/java-how-to-find-the-most-probable-string-in-a-list-of-strings)

you can use the way of string matching as you desire. there is also a github project for this at: 
https://github.com/northpoint/blur